# Multiple foreach loops in razor

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

I want to iterate through a collection using foreach, but I want properties of each object to determine where in the iteration it shows up. To fundamentally achieve this, I've used 2 foreach loops to first grab the primary list, then to grab the secondary list. The value is **DEPtxt** and the properties containing the value are **Course_Departments** and **Course_Departments2**

```
@foreach (ContentNode node in pgnodes.Where(x => x.Data.Course_Departments.ToString() == DEPtxt)){

                <li class="sys_subitem" style="display: list-item;"><a title="@node.Title" href="@node.Path">@node.Title</a></li>  
            }
            @foreach (ContentNode node in pgnodes.Where(x => x.Data.Course_Departments2.ToString() == DEPtxt)){

                <li class="sys_subitem" style="display: list-item;"><a title="@node.Title" href="@node.Path">@node.Title</a></li>  
            }
```

To put into context the Linq query has grabbed all objects that have a string value in one of 2 properties of the objects. I want the foreach loop to show all objects that have it in **Course_Departments** first, then to **Course_Departments2** after that.

Are multiple foreach loops the best way to do this?

Do I have to sort at the query? Do I have to create a list that sorts it? I want to hit the data store as little as possible and have the razor engine do most of the work.

Thanks!

Comment: is there fundamentally anything different between collection 1 and 2?

Comment: It's grabbing from the same collection, difference is that one loop has the value in a primary primary, the other has it in a secondary property.

Comment: couldn't you just loop the same thing but do    x => x.Data.Course_Departments.value1.ToString() == DEPtxt    and   x => x.Data.Course_Departments.value2.ToString() == DEPtxt

Comment: That's what I've done, I want to know if there's a better way as it seems like this would cause an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: seems to me you should go with my answer and sort the items ahead of time and pass the sorted list

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get a sorted list of items to display from a collection you should always do the sorting of items and the manipulations outside the view if at all possible.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment as this doesn't really offer any solution/answer, this is more of a Suggestion with no example/source code.

Comment: This answers partially a couple of the questions and not all answers absolutely require examples/source code. especially, because the questions are not for coding errors but rather practices.

Comment: you can provide examples that can help him to use it in better way rather than multiple foreach loop.

Comment: How exactly with the given information and no knowledge of his structure should I show him how to sort his items? Additionally, he is not asking for an example he is asking for a better way if possible.